# Autonomous Turtlebot map building

Tags: navigation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

G'day,
I'm looking to have my turtlebot autonomously build a map of an area, without needing to be manually teleoperated or working on an existing map.

I see this as a logical extension of the tutorial: "SLAM Map Building with TurtleBot", with the addition of some basic behaviour to seek out "unknown" areas instead of relying on teleoperation.

Just wondering if anyone else has already done something like this to serve as a starting point.

In general with ROS I find the low level tasks quite intuitive and well covered in tutorials (for example all of the turtlebot tutorials) but haven't seen any good examples of how these might all come together in "higher level robot behaviour".
For instance it would be great to see some code examples for a robot that can play a game that involves sensing, planning and execution. A turtlebot that could play RoboCup soccer would be a perfect example.

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27749/autonomous-turtlebot-map-building/) by [MarkStodden](https://answers.ros.org/users/1800/markstodden/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2012-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is the [exploration stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/exploration). I never tried it out though.

I think the problem with high-level applications is that they are very environment and robot specific. For the PR2, a few examples come into my mind: [tabletop manipulation](http://ros.org/wiki/object_manipulation), [beer fetching](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_drinks) (quite outdated I think), the pool billiard demo (also quite outdated), and a few more.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-02-16**:
I tried running the exploration stack on the PR2 once, with moderate success. It does exactly what you're looking for, if works.

**Comment by [MarkStodden](https://answers.ros.org/users/1800/markstodden/) on 2012-02-17**:
Thanks, this is exactly what I was after! I'll post back with my findings when I try this stack with my Turtlebot. And even if I have troubles with it, the stack will be an excellent starting point for writing something similar myself

**Comment by [d](https://answers.ros.org/users/19443/d/) on 2014-07-27**:
what is your experience with /explore so far? it's been a hit and miss for us. we would like to build autonomous map building for our robot too.